# How to automate App Pools to be Recycled when specified error log happened?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, application-pool

I need a powershell script to automate recycling App Pools when specified error log happens from eventviewer and sending a mail with details and recycling action
Any one Help me please ?

Comment: Assume that everything can be done in PowerShell, then trigger your PowerShell script from event log entries, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wincat/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event

Answer (score 0):

In Lex Li's document, you can set powershell script which be triggered by windows event.

Then, you need to set powershell script to [recycle app pool.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/restart-webapppool?view=winserver2012-ps)

```
IIS:\>Restart-WebAppPool PoolName
```

Comment: I need powershell script to do it not from event viewer console

Comment: Yes, all application pool recycling is performed through powershell, not event viewer.